# Is there an elementary proof of the convolution theorem?

Tags: fourier-analysis, convolution

Is there a way, without using much extra theory (other than the basic ideas used in textbooks deriving the Fourier transform for the first time, and ideally just using general theorems about integrals), of showing that

$$1.\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(t)h(x-t)dt\right)e^{-i2 \pi k x}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)e^{-i2 \pi k x}dx\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(x)e^{-i2 \pi k x}dx$$
$$2.\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)h(x)e^{-i2 \pi k x}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-i2 \pi t x}dx \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-i2 \pi (k-t) x}dx dt?$$

The two above threorems are the long-widned versions of the below:
$$1.f(x)=g(x)\otimes h(x)\Leftrightarrow F(k)=G(k)H(k)$$
$$2.f(x)=g(x) h(x)\Leftrightarrow F(k)=G(k) \otimes H(k).$$

Where $$g(x)\otimes h(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(t)h(x-t)dt$$
 $$f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(k)e^{i2\pi k x}dk \Leftrightarrow F(k)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-i2 \pi k x}dx.$$

Answer (score 3):

If $h(t),g(t)\in L_1( \mathbb{R} )$, then we have
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(t)h(x-t)dt\right)e^{-i2 \pi k x}dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(t)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(x-t)e^{-i2 \pi k x}dx dt .$$

Using the change of variables $x-t=y$ gives

$$ = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(t)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(y)e^{-i2 \pi k (y+t) }dy dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(t)e^{-i2 \pi k t }dt\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(y)e^{-i2 \pi k y } dy \,. $$

Comment: Just to stress this for OP: It is _crucial_ (for this proof) that $h,g$ be in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$. If they are not, the Fourier transform need not exist as an integral transform. It is true that this identity can be extended to other spaces, like $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, but conceptually it is a trickier thing to do than in the case of both functions being in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$.